# Theano: How to take a "matrix outer product" where the elements are matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, theano

Basically, I have 2 tensors: A, where A.shape = `(N, H, D)`, and B, where B.shape = `(K, H, D)`. What I would like to do is to get a tensor, C, with shape `(N, K, D, H)` such that :

```
C[i, j, :, :] = A[i, :, :] * B[j, :, :].
```

Can this be done efficiently in Theano?

Side note: The actual end result that I would like to achieve is to have a tensor, E, of shape `(N, K, D)` such that :

```
E[i, j, :] = (A[i, :, :]*B[j, :, :]).sum(0)
```

So, if there is a way to get this directly, I would prefer it (saves on space hopefully).

Comment: Which dimension do you want to sum over?  The first, 0? or 'H', which is 2nd to the last in the original arrays?

Comment: In `numpy` this could be expressed as `np.einsum('nhd,khd->nkd', A, B)`

Comment: I would like to do it over H. That should be sum(1) assuming that the tensor is of shape (1, H, D) before the summation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in Theano though?

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be suggested that uses [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(A[:,None]*B).sum(2)
```

Please note that the intermediate array being created would be of shape `(N, K, H, D)` before sum-reduction on `axis=2` reduces it to `(N,K,D).`

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something like this in the end but I was afraid that it would create this huge tensor which may be prohibitive when working on the GPU. But not sure if it is yet.

Comment: @Theo That's right, there is a significant amount of memory overhead here.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll start out with this solution and see if it works for the typical sizes that I'll be working with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the final three dimensional result `E` without creating the large intermediate array using [`batched_dot`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.batched_dot):

```
import theano.tensor as tt
A = tt.tensor3('A')  # A.shape = (D, N, H)
B = tt.tensor3('B')  # B.shape = (D, H, K)
E = tt.batched_dot(A, B)  # E.shape = (D, N, K)
```

Unfortunately this requires you to permute the dimensions on your input and output arrays. Though this can be done with [`dimshuffle`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.dimshuffle) in Theano it seems `batched_dot` can't cope with arbitrarily strided arrays and so the following raises a `ValueError: Some matrix has no unit stride` when `E` is evaluated:

```
import theano.tensor as tt
A = tt.tensor3('A')  # A.shape = (N, H, D)
B = tt.tensor3('B')  # B.shape = (K, H, D)
A_perm = A.dimshuffle((2, 0, 1))  # A_perm.shape = (D, N, H)
B_perm = B.dimshuffle((2, 1, 0))  # B_perm.shape = (D, H, K)
E_perm = tt.batched_dot(A_perm, B_perm)  # E_perm.shape = (D, N, K)
E = E_perm.dimshuffle((1, 2, 0))  # E.shape = (N, K, D)
```

`batched_dot` uses [`scan`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html) along the first (size `D`) dimension. As `scan` is performed sequentially this could be computationally less efficient than computing all the products in parallel if running on a GPU.

You can tradeoff between the memory efficiency of the `batched_dot` approach and parallelism in the broadcasting approach using `scan` explicitly. Idea would be to calculate the full product `C` for batches of size `M` in parallel (assuming `M` is an exact factor of `D`), iterating over batches with `scan`:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as tt
A = tt.tensor3('A')  # A.shape = (N, H, D)
B = tt.tensor3('B')  # B.shape = (K, H, D)
A_batched = A.reshape((N, H, M, D / M))
B_batched = B.reshape((K, H, M, D / M))
E_batched, _ = th.scan(
    lambda a, b: (a[:, :, None, :] * b[:, :, :, None]).sum(1),
    sequences=[A_batched.T, B_batched.T]
)
E = E_batched.reshape((D, K, N)).T  # E.shape = (N, K, D)
```